# Are slow import runtimes normal on single-board computers like an Omega Onion2+?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I'm working with an Omega Onion 2+, and running some Python3 programs. By far the longest runtime constraint on the programs are the import statements. On my MacBook, importing the 15 modules I need to import takes 0.34 seconds. On the Omega, it takes an average of 35 seconds. Is this a normal runtime for an Omega? Is it just because the computer lacks power?